# weird camera path with good marker tracking solve error

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I have a drone footage taken with Phantom 3 Pro and I want to solve the camera path. The markers are fairly stable with a solve error less than 1. Still the camera path is pretty much crazy. I used LocScale for the motion model of the markers, since with Perspective the tracking was impossible to follow.

Here is the youtube link for the screen capture movie:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8uNgkwqE_s&feature=youtu.be](https://youtu.be/S8uNgkwqE_s)

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see that the end of the camera move is tracked well, this is because there markers with different depth which are very consistent. In the beginning there is little depth information (since the markers are only on the tower) and most of them removed very quickly. You don't have a frame with the beginning markers in correlation to anything in the background.

Comment: Have you tried using different keyframes for the camera solve?